# Firebase and Man In the Middle Attack

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-security

We are doing an app and would like to use Firebase.

The security requirements for the app state that certificate pinning should be implemented to protect the app from Man In The Middle Attacks.

This does not seem possible as far as we can tell from the documentation. Is there anyone who knows enough about Firebase to know if this is possible or indeed necessary to maintain tight security

Best

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Comment: It is not possible and according to Firebase support  it is not emminent

Answer (score 0):

We were successfully able to implement Certificate Pinning in our React Native application using the following library.

[React Native SSL Pinning](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ssl-pinning)